# I2C slave module in Verilog does not acknowledge

Tags: verilog, i2c

I wrote this I2C slave module in Verilog:

```
module I2CSlave(
input iSCL,
input iI2C_CLK,
inout bSDA,
output reg [7:0] odata,
output reg oread,
output wire oactive
);    

reg incycle = 1'b0;
reg pSDA;
reg pSCL;
always @(posedge iI2C_CLK) begin
    if ((pSCL) && (iSCL) && (pSDA) && (~bSDA)) begin
        incycle <= 1;
    end
    if ((pSCL) && (iSCL) && (~pSDA) && (bSDA)) begin
        incycle <= 0;
    end
    pSDA <= bSDA;
    pSCL <= iSCL;
end

assign oactive = incycle;

localparam STATE_IDLE = 0;
localparam STATE_ADDR = 1;
localparam STATE_RW = 2;
localparam STATE_ACK = 3;
localparam STATE_DATA = 4;
localparam STATE_ACK2 = 5;

reg [7:0] i = 0;
reg [7:0] state = STATE_IDLE;
reg [6:0] addr = 7'h03;
reg addr_match = 1;
reg rw;

reg lSDA;
always @(posedge iSCL) lSDA <= bSDA;

assign bSDA = ((state == STATE_ACK) || (state == STATE_ACK2)) ? 0 : 1'bz;
assign oread = (state == STATE_ACK2);
assign ostate = i;

always @(negedge iSCL or negedge incycle) begin
    if (~incycle) begin
        state <= STATE_IDLE;
        addr_match <= 1;
    end
    else if (addr_match) begin
        case (state)
            STATE_IDLE: begin               
                state <= STATE_ADDR;
                i <= 7;
            end
            STATE_ADDR: begin
                if (addr[i-1] != lSDA) addr_match <= 0;
                if (i == 1) begin
                    state <= STATE_RW;
                    i <= i - 1;
                end
                else i <= i - 1;
            end
            STATE_RW: begin
                rw <= lSDA;
                state <= STATE_ACK;
            end
            STATE_ACK: begin
                state <= STATE_DATA;
                i = 7;
            end
            STATE_DATA : begin
                odata[i] <= lSDA;
                if (i == 0) state <= STATE_ACK2;
                else i <= i - 1;
            end
            STATE_ACK2: begin
                state <= STATE_DATA;
                i = 7;
            end
        endcase
    end
end

endmodule
```

As of now it should just read the data sent by master. It seems to work well in simulation, but when I upload it into the FPGA, sometimes everything is OK, however sometimes it does not acknowledge the data sent by master and it just seems to ignore them. I am newbie in Verilog, so I hope, this is not a silly question.

Comment: The testbench only tries to initiate the communication by sending the address and then it sends 1 byte of data. Also the communication must be sped up in simulation, because there is only 100 us available in Quartus Lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause for random fails while running on real hardware is that you didn't synchronize inputs.

You are sampling slowly changing signals (i2c bus will have a long slopes) that are truly asynchronous to your design's clock. Depending on your luck, you will have random violations for setup/hold times of your fpga's d-flops, which results in metastability issues. The same value in the register might be treated differently in multiple parts of the chip. That will wreak havoc in your i2c slave's logic.

You must synchronize asynchronous inputs, in the simplest case passing it through a couple of registers before feeding it to the module's fsm.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code which could cause mismatch in behavior in simulation and synthesis. For example, the following is not synthesizable and is ignored by synthesis tools. So, your initial state would be different. Check your logs for warnings. Do not use declaration assignments for `regs`. (ok for wires).

```
reg [7:0] i = 0;
reg [7:0] state = STATE_IDLE;
reg [6:0] addr = 7'h03;
reg addr_match = 1;
```

The above means that you initialization does not work.

You messed up blocking and non-blocking assignments in the state machine. Make sure that you use nbas in all places where 'i = 7'. it should be

```
i <= 7;
```

And make sure that you test enough initialization and different conditions in simulation.

Comment: Why not synthesizable? Yes, in ASIC you must reset registers explicitly, but sram-based fpga will definitely initialize registers to a specified values, and synthesizer will not complain. Or maybe it's only Altera/Xilinx allows this?

Comment: Ok, found a good answer to this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/340338/127801

Comment: Thanks for tip. I replaced the incorrect blocking assignments by the non-blocking ones. Then I removed the unnecessary initializations and I moved the needed ones into initial block. So the uninitialized registers should be equal to 0, right? The problem is, that the FPGA still behaves in the same way. What else exactly should I test in the simulation?

Comment: @Vlad I am using Altera, so it probably should work even the way I had it in my original design, as you have written, but I have also tried to avoid it, as Serge has written, nevertheless it behaves the same way in both cases.

Comment: @MartinSchmied you have to remember that initial blocks are not synthesizable as well. You need to create a reset condition where you can initialize your variables.

Comment: My problem is already solved thanks to Vlad. This was obviously not the problem, because on Altera both register initializations and initial blocks are synthesizable.